# Lookup column showing as "Required info"

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, lookup-column, administration

I have a list that is using a lookup from another list - client name. As part of that column I am able to select "Add additional columns from source list".

I have selected a couple of these fields - one of the fields is a date field and despite the originating column not requiring that data is added, is showing as "Required info" on the record where this field is blank. Is there any means to stop this appearing? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the lookup column settings and make it as non-required column.

Follow steps:

1. Go to your SharePoint list
2. Click on column name header. Select **Column settings** > **Edit**

   [image]
3. Click on **More options** on column settings pane
4. Toggle **Require that this column contains information** option to **No**
5. Save

[image]

Comment: thanks Ganesh - unfortunately this is not available for these fields

Comment: This setting is available for main lookup column in modern experience.

Comment: sorry I thought you were referring to the other fields - thanks!

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

"Require that this column contains information" is enabled on your lookup column, this means that the additional columns also have this setting enabled. You can disable the "required" option for the additional columns by following these steps:

1. Go to the list, click the cog on the top right and select list settings
2. In list settings, select the additional column from the columns section:

[image]

3. Set the option "Require that this column contains information" to "No"

[image]

You should no longer see "Required info" in the additional column if it is empty.

Comment: thanks - I tried that but it initially did not update the date field, so I deselected the additional field in "Add additional columns from source list" and then reselected it again - that sorted it! thanks for your help!